# Can anyone help me to match a dot in perl

Tags: perl

```
  if( $file =~ /.txt/ or $file =~ /.pl/){
        open(readFile,"<$file") ;
        @m=<readFile>;
        open(writeFile, ">$file") ;
        print  writeFile" following files are updated ";
        print writeFile  @m; 
        close writeFile ;
     }
```

This code is not matching  the  . Txt its just matching txt what can i do to match the dot

Comment: You realise that this code doesn't compile? (you can't use `read` as a filehandler, and there is no capital `i` in `if`) ... (about how to match a dot, see @Arunesh Singh's answer)

Comment: @Dada: It's a *file handle* a file handler is something completely different.

Comment: @Borodin whups, my poor english may have failed me... my bad, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you sure about the blank between the dot `.` and `txt`? Really `/. txt/`? Besides that the code seems strange to me. It adds " following files are updated " to the beginning of a file if its filename ends in ".txt" or ".pl". But that would be another question (if at all).

Comment: @perl  dog... Yes u r right this script is going to do that only and there is no space between .  And txt

Comment: I have written this code from my mobile, thats why there are some syntax errors so please ignore them

Comment: LOL, I exactly know what you mean. **tl;dr Paste! your code.** Posting code from a mobile is a mess. It's not SO's fault, it simply doesn't work properly because of all the mobile's auto-thingies. That is why it is strongly recommended to **paste** the code you have in your editor instead of keying it in, so we can face the _very same_ code you have and not something "approximately like" or "almost similar to" your code. We don't know which of the errors are due to your spell-checker and which you made on your own.

Comment: @Perl Dog... None of the errors are committed by me. It's coz of the mob and plus have one more doubt i'm using glob for finding the files and it works for a single directory but for director within a directory it is not that good as i have to give path for each dir

Comment: So you need to recursively find your files? That would be another question. Currently you asked how to match a dot `.` in a regex. This question was answered. Please post another question or -- even better -- see whether that was asked & answered before. I'm sure it was.

Answer (score 6):

`.` by default matches any character except newline.
For matching `.` literally you need to escape it in regex.

```
if( $file =~ /\.txt/ or $file =~ /\.pl/) {
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding two dollars: `if ( $file =~ /\.txt$/ or $file =~ /.pl$/ ) {…` to avoid false-positives (like `$file='sim.ply-wrong'`).

Comment: @PerlDog You should use `\z` instead of `$` unless you want `"file.txt\n"` to be considered a valid file name.

Comment: @SinanÜnür You are right. Thank you. I'm so used to `chomp`ing my input that I always forget about `\z` vs. `$` because then there's no difference.

Comment: It's best not to have to think whether it makes a difference or not (regardless of whether you are the coder or the reader).